# SQL Server : conditional columns (output schema change)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, schema, conditional-statements

I have a simple yet frustrating scenario.

Simplified

```
create procedure [dbo].[test] 
    @bShow bit = 0
as
begin
    if(@bShow = 0)
        SELECT name, surname 
        FROM table_person
    ELSE
        SELECT name, surname, email 
        FROM table_person
end
```

I know I can use dynamic SQL, wrap it all up as a string with conditions to determine if the additional column should be displayed.

I can also dump all the data into a #temp table with the additional column and simply drop that column if the condition is not met and select all from the temp table.

However the above has other implications, the dynamic sql would mean that SQL would not optimise and cache my procedure as well as it should and the second approach (drop unwanted from #temp) would mean that for each record the additional columns would be retrieved regardless if it is used.

I could also use an if statement with 2 seperate selects but again for SQL post optimisation it is not ideal as a different execution path would be used each time the proc is executed.

The additional columns in my specific requirement is a rather taxing calculation that has a drastic effect on my performance, hence the paramater to show them only if needed, it would use a pivot table to join the additional columns.

I have tried CTE's and subqueries and pretty much every other avenue I can think of.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I didn't understand this, but can you do:

```
create procedure [dbo].[test] 
    @bShow bit = 0
as
begin
        SELECT name, surname, CASE WHEN @bShow = 0 THEN email ELSE NULL
        FROM table_person
end
```